# Clojure not requiring a cljc file

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I need to share a namespace between my Clojure (Garden) and my ClojureScript (Reagent).

Currently the project folder looks like this:

```
src/
  clj/
    name/
      css.clj
  cljs/
    name/
      core.cljs
  cljc/
    name/
      config.cljc
```

The `config.cljc` file has the following namespace: `(ns name.config)`.

I've tried to reference this namespace from inside `clj/name/css.clj` with a require.

```
(ns name.css
  (:require [name.config :as config]))
```

However, this results in a compile error from Garden.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate name/config__init.class or name/config.clj on classpath.

I guess it's not even checking for `cljc` files.

I added `"src/cljc"` to the `:source-paths` vector in `project.clj` and `:garden :builds` but I get the same error even after restarting the build processes.

I see this behaviour on Clojure 1.7.0 and 1.8.0.

It might also be worth mentioning that it works without issues in ClojureScript (with Figwheel handling the build). I can require and use the new namespace without problems.

It seems like I must be missing something really simple, because none of the documentation around `.cljc` files even mentions requiring them.

Answer (score 5):

Check if you’re using Clojure 1.7 or above in your `project.clj`. This error message:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate name/config__init.class or name/config.clj on classpath.

indicates that you’re using Clojure 1.6 or below, as those versions of Clojure only know to look for `.class` or `.clj` files.

Comment: `project.clj` has `org.clojure/clojure` at `"1.7.0"` and when I boot up a REPL it confirms `Clojure 1.7.0`. Anything else that needs to be set in `project.clj`?

Comment: I get the same problem when I use 1.8.0 too.

Comment: What version of Leinigen are you using? You might try a more recent one if it exists.

Comment: @DanPrince can you share your project somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when I moved a file from .clj to .cljc in my project. I did `lein clean` but that had no effect. Eventually I renamed the module namespace and that fixed it.

(My guess is that there was some sort of cache of compiled modules and it was referencing a module which no longer existed, but the cljc wasn't re-compiled because a module of that name was still cached.)

When I renamed the module namespace it worked, with no other changes to the code.